# calculate sum for values in SQL for display per month name

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

i have a table with the following layout.

```
Email Blast Table

EmailBlastId |  FrequencyId | UserId
---------------------------------
1            |   5          |   1
2            |   2          |   1
3            |   4          |   1


Frequency Table

Id | Frequency 
------------
 1 |  Daily
 2 |  Weekly
 3 |  Monthly
 4 |  Quarterly
 5 |  Bi-weekly
```

I need to come up with a grid display on my asp.net page as follows.

```
Email blasts per month.

UserId | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr |..... Dec | Cumulative
-----------------------------------------------------
1        7      6     6     7          6     #xx
```

The only way I can think of doing this is as below, for each month have a case statement.

```
select SUM(
        CASE WHEN FrequencyId = 1 THEN 31 
        WHEN FrequencyId = 2 THEN 4
        WHEN FrequencyId = 3 THEN 1
        WHEN FrequencyId = 4 THEN 1
        WHEN FrequencyId = 5 THEN 2 END) AS Jan, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN FrequencyId = 1 THEN 28 (29 - leap year)
        WHEN FrequencyId = 2 THEN 4
        WHEN FrequencyId = 3 THEN 1
        WHEN FrequencyId = 4 THEN 0
        WHEN FrequencyId = 5 THEN 2 END) AS Feb, etc etc
FROM EmailBlast 
Group BY UserId
```

Any other better way of achieving the same?

Comment: Are you sure your displaying the right data?  Just because something is configured to go out a certain times a period doesn't mean that it did.  I may be wrong as to what you are doing but I would think it would be better to count the actual number of blasts done per month...

Comment: Shouldn't your last CASE be WHEN FrequencyId = 5 THEN 2

Comment: @chris, These blasts are actually schedulable. The display shows how many times the emails WILL be sent with the current frequencies. Trust me, this is a requirement so no point trying to see if thats right or wrong. been there, done that.

Comment: @Lost, you are correct. question updated.

Comment: @Alex J: just making sure.  It's sometimes hard to tell. ;)

Comment: This is kind of tricky, isn't it? In particular "weekkly" will be a bit hard to handle since there are overlaps between months. I would just handle this on the application side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this for any given year? I'm going to assume you want the schedule for the current year. If you want a future year you can always change the `DECLARE @now` to specify any future date.

"Once in 2 weeks" (usually known as "bi-weekly") doesn't fit well into monthly buckets (except for February in a non-leap year). Should that possibly be changed to "Twice a month"?

Also, why not store the coefficient in the Frequency table, adding a column called "PerMonth"? Then you only have to deal with the Daily and Quarterly cases (and is it an arbitrary choice that this will happen only in January, April, and so on?).

Assuming that some of this is flexible, here is what I would suggest, assuming this very minor change to the table schema:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Frequency 
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Frequency VARCHAR(32),
    PerMonth TINYINT
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.EmailBlast 
(
    Id INT,
    FrequencyId INT,
    UserId INT
);
```

And this sample data:

```
INSERT dbo.Frequency(Id, Frequency, PerMonth)
  SELECT 1, 'Daily', NULL
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Weekly', 4
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Monthly', 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'Quarterly', NULL
  UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'Twice a month', 2;

INSERT dbo.EmailBlast(Id, FrequencyId, UserId)
  SELECT 1, 5, 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2, 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 4, 1;
```

We can accomplish this using a very complex query (but we don't have to hard-code those month numbers):

```
DECLARE @now DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE @Jan1 DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, 1-MONTH(@now), DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(@now), @now));

WITH n(m) AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 12 m = number
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values
        WHERE number > 0 GROUP BY number
),
months(MNum, MName, StartDate, NumDays) AS
(    SELECT m, mn = CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, m-1, @Jan1))),
        DATEADD(MONTH, m-1, @Jan1), 
        DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, m-1, @Jan1), DATEADD(MONTH, m, @Jan1))
    FROM n
),
grp AS
(
    SELECT UserId, MName, c = SUM (
        CASE x.Id WHEN 1 THEN NumDays
            WHEN 4 THEN CASE WHEN MNum % 3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            ELSE x.PerMonth END )
    FROM months CROSS JOIN (SELECT e.UserId, f.* 
        FROM EmailBlast AS e 
        INNER JOIN Frequency AS f
        ON e.FrequencyId = f.Id) AS x
    GROUP BY UserId, MName
),
cumulative(UserId, total) AS
(
    SELECT UserId, SUM(c)
      FROM grp GROUP BY UserID
),
pivoted AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT UserId, c, MName FROM grp) AS grp 
    PIVOT(MAX(c) FOR MName IN (
        [Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec])
    ) AS pvt
)
SELECT p.*, c.total 
    FROM pivoted AS p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cumulative AS c
    ON p.UserId = c.UserId;
```

Results:

```
UserId  Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec total
1       7   6   6   7   6   6   7   6   6   7   6   6   76
```

Clean up:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.EmailBlast, dbo.Frequency;
GO
```

In fact the schema change I suggested doesn't really buy you much, it just saves you two additional `CASE` branches inside the `grp` CTE. Peanuts, overall.

Comment: my head is bursting with all the amount of thought I need to put in to this:).. thanks, i'm going to take a break and look at this later today.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer for now. It looks like the closest solution. Although I'm going to try and get the requirement changed to an estimated number, probably not 100% accurate. Nice sql with most things I have not seen.

Comment: +1. I agree that this is a great way to get an estimate.  You should be good as long as everyone is okay with it just being close.  Although I might be misreading this but it appears to completely ignore quarterly.

Comment: @Chris quarterly is there. See how Jan, Apr, Jul and Oct have 7? The extra mailing in those months is due to quarterly (see the part of the case where I check for `MNum % 3 = 1`).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going to end up with a lot more complicated logic.  Sure Jan has 31 days.. but Feb doesn't... and Feb changes depending on the year.  Next, are email blasts sent even on weekends and holidays or are certain days skipped for various reasons...  If that's the case then the number of business days for a given month changes each year.

Next the number of full weeks in a given month also changes year by year.  What happens to those extra 4 half weeks?  Do they go on the current or next month?  What method are you using to determine that?  For an example of how complicated this gets read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date  Specifically the part where it talks about the first week, which actually has 9 different definitions.

I'm usually not one to say this, but you might be better off writing this with regular code instead of a sql query.  Just issue a 'select * from emailblast where userid = xxx' and transform it using a variety of code methods.

Comment: quite honestly, i'm at a loss here too. Perhaps better to do it in the code, but how, wouldn't it have the same problems. Didn't think it would be this complicated when I looked at it first.

Comment: @Alex J: Yes, you have the same problems.  Just better /faster tools to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider adding a 3rd table called something like Schedule.

You could structure it like this:

```
MONTH_NAME
DAILY_COUNT
WEEKLY_COUNT
MONTHLY_COUNT
QUARTERLY_COUNT
BIWEEKLY_COUNT
```

The record for JAN would be

```
JAN
31
4
1
1
2
```

Or you could structure it like this:

```
MONTH_NAME 
FREQUENCY_ID 
EMAIL_COUNT
```

and have multiple records for each month:

```
JAN   1   31
JAN   2    4
JAN   3    1
JAN   4    1
JAN   5    2
```

I let you figure out if the logic to retrieve this is better than your CASE structure.

Comment: You'd need one for each year to account for February and also which weeks technically fall in each month from year to year.

Comment: True.  Plenty of upkeep with the changing counts based on the calendar, but maybe better to do that in a table instead of the code.

Comment: Well, the code can always tell what year it is, or you can tell it which year to use if you don't want it to base February's count on the current year.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you're looking for.  Suggestion 1 would be to track your **actual** email blasts (with a date :-).

Without actual dates, whatever you come-up with for one month will be the same for every month.

Anyway, If you're going to generalize, then I'd suggest using something other than ints -- like maybe floats or decimals.  Since your output based on the tables listed in your post can only ever approximate what actually happens (e.g., January actually has 4-1/2 weeks, not 4), you'll have a compounding error-bounds over any range of months -- getting worse, the further out you extrapolate.  If you output an entire 12 months, for example, your extrapolation will under-estimate by over 4 weeks.

If you use floats or decimals, then you'll be able to come much closer to what actually happens.  For starters: find a common unit of measure (I'd suggest using a "day")  E.g., 1 month = 365/12 days; 1 quarter = 365/4 days; 1 2week = 14 days; etc.

If you do that -- then your user who had one 1 per quarter actually had 1 per 91.25 days; 1 per week turns into 1 per 7 days; 1 per BiWeek turns into 1 per 14 days.

```
**EDIT** -- Incidentally, you could store the per-day value in your reference table, so you didn't have to calculate it each time.  For example:
Frequency Table

Id | Frequency         | Value
-------------------------------
 1 |  Daily            | 1.0
 2 |  Weekly           | .14286
 3 |  Monthly          | .03288
 4 |  Quarterly        | .01096
 5 |  Once in 2 weeks  | .07143
```

Now do math -- (1/91.25 + 1/7 + 1/14) needs a common denom (like maybe 91.25 * 14), so it becomes (14/1277.5 + 182.5/1277.5 + 91.25/1277.5).

That adds-up to 287.75/1277.5, or .225 emails per day.

Since there are 365/12 days per month, multiple .225 * (365/12) to get 6.85 emails per month.

Your output would then look something like this:

```
Email blasts per month.

UserId | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr |..... Dec | Cumulative
-----------------------------------------------------
1        6.85  6.85  6.85  6.85     6.85     #xx
```

The math may seem a little tedious, but once you step it out on your code, you'll never have to do it again.  Your results will be more accurate (I rounded to 2 decimal places, but you could go further out if you wanted to).  And if your company is using this data to determine budgets / potential income for the upcoming year, that might be worth it.

Also worth mentioning is that after YOU get done extrapolating (and the error bounds that entails), your consumers of this output will do THEIR OWN extrapolating, not on the raw data, but on your output.  So it's kind of a double-whammy of error bounds.  The more accurate you can be early-on, the more reliable these numbers will be at each subsequent levels.

Comment: Why would you use a `FLOAT` instead of a `DECIMAL`? I don't think you need that level of approximation. :-)

Comment: @Aaron -- good point -- I guess if you need to convert the calc'd value back to the frequency, decimals would be better.  But either way...as long as it's not an int :-).